# SQL How to use Count and Group By WXY and Z

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, count, group-by

Let's say I'm trying to count the number of elements in W, X, Y, and Z. I don't care about specific numbers within WXY, and I only care about Z. is there a way I can make something like this:

```
column | count
---------------
 WXY   |  10
  Z    |  5
```

instead of

```
column | count
---------------
  W    |  2
  X    |  3
  Y    |  5
  Z    |  5
```

Comment: Please use Ctrl+K, not a bunch of `&nbsp;` and `<br>` tags for code formatting.

Comment: This is tagged as sql-server and postgresql. Which database version are you using? If you need a solution for both, then do you need the same query to work on both versions or will separate queries for each version work?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [column] = CASE 
  WHEN [column] IN ('W','X','Y') THEN 'WXY' ELSE 'Z' END,
  [count] = COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.[table]
WHERE [column] IN ('W','X','Y','Z')
  GROUP BY CASE 
  WHEN [column] IN ('W','X','Y') THEN 'WXY' ELSE 'Z' END
ORDER BY [column];
```

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/36efa/1)

```
select case 
    when c in ('W', 'X', 'Y') then 'XYZ'
    else 'Z' end as c,
    count(*)
from t
group by 1
```

Comment: This will work with PostGreSQL but not SQL Server. The question is tagged with both, so it's not clear what the OP needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with a Common Table Expression (CTE) and aggregate the data before trying to get a count of the records.

It works with both PostgreSQL and SQL Server (but there are problem if you name a column "column").

PostgreSQL: <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/36efa/12)</kbd>
SQL Server: <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36efa6/7)</kbd>

```
;with aggData as
(
   select case 
             when c = 'Z' then 'Z'
             else 'WXY' 
          end as col
   from t
)
select col, count(*)
from aggData
group by col
```

Here is documentation on using [CTEs with SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [CTEs with PostGreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html).